# libgdx - changing sprite color to white

Tags: android, libgdx, fragment-shader

I want to colorize a sprite so that RGB channels are all 1 and alpha remains unchanged.
I gather this should be done with shaders, but the two accepted answers on StackOverflow ([Change sprite color into white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20553664/change-sprite-color-into-white) and [libgdx changing sprite color while hurt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099103/libgdx-changing-sprite-color-while-hurt)) don't work for me - the result is transparent, and they don't work on http://shdr.bkcore.com/ either

Comment: I did this using a shader. I'll get back to you later today with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to replace the RGB each with 1.0 in the fragment shader.

**Vertex shader-- This is like the one in SpriteBatch with vertex color removed since you aren't using it:**

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

void main()
{
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position;
}
```

**Fragment shader-- grab just the alpha value from the texture.:**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision lowp float; //since the only value we're storing is part of a color
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    float alpha = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).a;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, alpha);
}
```